# populating a nesting dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

having trouble populating a nested dictionary and retaining previously populated keys. see this example:

```
fulldict={}
keys=['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

for key in keys:
    for i in xrange(3):
        x1 = np.random.randn(10)
        y1 = np.random.randn(10)
        fulldict[key] = {i:pd.DataFrame({'x1':x1, 'y1': y1})}
```

my intent is that `fulldict['key1']` should contain 3 dictionaries with keys 0,1,2. but only the last key (2) is stored.

any suggestions appreciated

Comment: You are reassigning the `fulldict[key]` each time, did you mean `fulldict[key][i] = pd.DataFrame({'x1':x1, 'y1': y1})`. You will need `fulldict[key] = {}` in the outer `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning the `fulldict[key]` each time, so initialize `fulldict[key] = {}` and use `i` as a key:

```
for key in keys:
    fulldict[key] = {}
    for i in xrange(3):
        x1 = np.random.randn(10)
        y1 = np.random.randn(10)
        fulldict[key][i] = pd.DataFrame({'x1':x1, 'y1': y1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could resort to a dict comprehension for the inner dict (saves a few lookups):

```
import numpy as np

fulldict={}
keys=['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

draw = np.random.randn
for key in keys:
    fulldict[key] = {i: pd.DataFrame({'x1': draw(10), 'y1': draw(10)})
                     for i in xrange(3)}
```